# Jquery slider banner

Tags: jquery

There is a nifty flash banner located here: http://osc4.template-help.com/drupal_30779/. I was wondering if there is a jquery library out there that allows me to achieve the same effect. (click, slide,expand). Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not make it yourself? This is something which is really easy to code.

Comment: I am not very familiar with jquery

Comment: I am in the process in throwing a small mock up together on jsfiddle but not to toot my own website but I use a similar effect for my header if the link is not ok tell me and I will remove it but http://zobgib.com I would be happy to give you my js to work with if it is close to what you're looking for. Small modifications would allow mine to work just fine like your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote you a little answer that is a good start.  The working code is at http://jsfiddle.net/fxBjw/ here it is in pieces

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li class="block" id="a"></li>
        <li class="block" id="b"></li>
        <li class="block" id="c"></li>
        <li class="block" id="d"></li>
        <li class="block" id="e"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    height: 100px;
    width: 245px;
    border: #000 1px solid;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/*I am not great with css so the only thing i think you could do better is the positioning.
Maybe style everything in JS and use position absolute
there also may be a better way to handle the overflow but this is a good jq start*/
.block {
    width: 45px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#a {
    background: url(http://rndimg.com/ImageStore/OilPaintingOrange/50x100_OilPaintingOrange_d190c94ef0c845399e2849fd7e9d54de.jpg);}
#b {
    background: url(http://rndimg.com/ImageStore/OilPaintingBlue/50x100_OilPaintingBlue_44398b9cfff447938d5b02c56e275611.jpg);}
#c {
background: url(http://rndimg.com/ImageStore/OilPaintingGreenReal/50x100_OilPaintingGreenReal_d3284c223f484ad584d4cc6d9de29ba5.jpg);
}
#d {background: url(http://rndimg.com/ImageStore/OilPaintingGreen/50x100_OilPaintingGreen_03938e7dbfa74b0f861d9a0851a34455.jpg); }
#e {background: url(http://rndimg.com/ImageStore/OilPaintingBlueReal/50x100_OilPaintingBlueReal_d2e4856d7e4e4224b42ced5cf6675132.jpg); }
```

JS

```
//This creates the click function in jquery
$('#container li').click(function (event) {
    //Create a var for the index of the LI
    var ind = $(this).index();
    //Move the LI right to the edge I am not good with stying so there is probably a better way to do this also in the CSS
    //The set up is you move it to the right * the number of elements it is in the list
    $(this).animate({
       'right': ind*50+'px'
    });
    //Now for all the other list items
    $('#container li').each(function () {
        //Check if the items are after the one clicked if so move them off to the right
    if ($(this).index() > ind) {
             $(this).animate({ 'left': '200px'});
        //if they are smaller mover them to the left
    } else if ($(this).index() < ind ){
        $(this).animate({ 'right': '200px'});
    }});
});
```

I did not add a reset button just click run again the return animate should be pretty straight forward.

PS. Thanks for giving me an excuse not to do my HW

Comment: oh wow thanks so much! will take me a while to go through your code but the fiddle looks like its exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Blender, this wouldn't be very hard to code.

If your not familiar go over to the documentation and get to know it. [The Jquery API](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)

also print off this cheat sheet -> [Jquery Cheat sheet](http://labs.impulsestudios.ca/downloads/impulse_studios-jquery_cheat_sheet-1.0.pdf)

The cheat sheet is handy if you want to quickly look something up.

You get start with something like this -> http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jQuery-common-accordion and then amend it to achieve the exact result you want.

depending how different what you want is it might be faster to amend an existing example rather than write completely from scratch.